# Assigning output from awk to variables

Tags: variables, awk, variable-assignment

I'm trying to create a bash script that ingests the output of another script `cpu_latency.bt`

The output of `cpu_latency.bt` is generated every second and looks similar to:

```
@usecs: 
[0]                    3 |@@@@@@@@@@                                          |
[1]                    5 |@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@                                   |
[2, 4)                 5 |@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@                                   |
[4, 8)                 0 |                                                    |
[8, 16)                5 |@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@                                   |
[16, 32)              15 |@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@|
[32, 64)               1 |@@@                                                 |
[64, 128)              0 |                                                    |
[128, 256)             1 |@@@                                                 |

@usecs: 
[0]                    1 |@@@                                                 |
[1]                    1 |@@@                                                 |
[2, 4)                 6 |@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@                              |
[4, 8)                 2 |@@@@@@@                                             |
[8, 16)                4 |@@@@@@@@@@@@@@                                      |
```

I am trying to capture ***only*** the first number after the `[` and then the number before the first `|` (so in the last line above that would be `8` and `4`

The script below is fairly close (with the exception of handling `[0]` and `[1]` lines):

```
duration=10
while read line
do
        echo $line | cut -d "|" -f1 | sed 's/\[//g; s/\,//g; s/)//g' | awk '{print $1,$3}' |
        while read key value; do
                print "The Key is "$key "and the Value is "$value
        done

done < <(timeout $duration cpu_latency.bt | grep "\[")
```

However the output it returns is not quite right:

```
Error: no such file "The Key is 16"
Error: no such file "and the Value is 10"
Error: no such file "The Key is 16"
Error: no such file "and the Value is 9"
```

Can recommend a better way of assigning the output of $1 and $3 to variables so I can write them out to a file?

Thanks
CiCa

---

@RavinderSingh13 I'm not sure if I I'm misunderstanding how I can use an array for this, but a little more work with a while loop has gotten me considerably closer to what I'm aiming for:

```
while read key value
do  
    echo `hostname`".cpu-lat."$key"\\"$value"\\`date +"%s"`"  >> /tmp/stats.out
done < <(
timeout $duration /root/bpftrace/cpu_latency.bt | awk '
match($0,/^\[[0-9]+/){
  val=substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-1)
  match($0,/[0-9]+ +\|/)
  val2=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  sub(/ +\|/,"",val2)
  print val,val2
  val=val2=""
}' )
```

Comment: What is the point of the shell loop in the final script in your question? You should read https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/133219, https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes, and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082 to learn how to deal with some of the general shell programming issues in your scripts and also run every shell script you write through https://www.shellcheck.net/ for help spotting some of the problems until you get some familiarity with shell programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're trying to do?

```
$ awk -F'[][,[:space:]]+' 'sub(/ \|.*/,""){print $2, $NF}' file
0 3
1 5
2 5
4 0
8 5
16 15
32 1
64 0
128 1
0 1
1 1
2 6
4 2
8 4
```

.

```
$ awk -v host="$(hostname)" -v date="$(date +%s)" -F'[][,[:space:]]+' '
    sub(/ \|.*/,"") { printf "%s.cpu-lat.%s\\%s\\%s\n", host, $2, $NF, date }
' file
mypc.cpu-lat.0\3\1576428453
mypc.cpu-lat.1\5\1576428453
mypc.cpu-lat.2\5\1576428453
mypc.cpu-lat.4\0\1576428453
mypc.cpu-lat.8\5\1576428453
mypc.cpu-lat.16\15\1576428453
mypc.cpu-lat.32\1\1576428453
mypc.cpu-lat.64\0\1576428453
mypc.cpu-lat.128\1\1576428453
mypc.cpu-lat.0\1\1576428453
mypc.cpu-lat.1\1\1576428453
mypc.cpu-lat.2\6\1576428453
mypc.cpu-lat.4\2\1576428453
mypc.cpu-lat.8\4\1576428453
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was trying to do! Thank you Sir. 

And Thank you to all other contributors of this thread, a lot learnt, and even more to learn :)

Answer (score 1):

***EDIT:*** After seeing OP's attempt from my code, adding following now.

```
awk -v host="$(hostname)" -v date="$(date +%s)" '
match($0,/^\[[0-9]+/){
  val=substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-1)
  match($0,/[0-9]+ +\|/)
  val2=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  sub(/ +\|/,"",val2)
  printf("%s.cpu-lat.%s\\%s\\%s\n", host, val, val2, date)
  val=val2=""
}' Input_file
```

---

---

Could you please try following. I have mentioned Input_file to pass to `awk` here in case you want to pass s command's output into awk then try like: `your_script | following awk code without Input_file`

```
awk '
match($0,/^\[[0-9]+/){
  val=substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-1)
  match($0,/[0-9]+ +\|/)
  val2=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  sub(/ +\|/,"",val2)
  print val,val2
  val=val2=""
}' Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -e 's/[^0-9]/ /g' lala  |gawk '{ print $1, substr($0,20,5) }'
```

The 'sed' remove all non-numbers
The 'awk' will print first argument, and from position 20, 5 characters of text. (Which can be changed to numeric by addin 0 to it):

```
sed -e 's/[^0-9]/ /g' lala  |gawk '{ print $1, 0+substr($0,20,5) }'
```

Of course, Ed is right!:

```
gawk '{ gsub(/[^0-9]/," "); print $1, 0+substr($0,20,5) }'
```

Comment: You never need sed when you're using awk. `sed -e 's/[^0-9]/ /g' lala  |gawk '{ print $1, substr($0,20,5) }'` = `awk '{gsub(/[^0-9]/," "); print $1, substr($0,20,5) }' lala`.